# Can't insert date vaiable into SQL string in PHP

Tags: php, database

Why does this not work in PHP?

```
$dato = '2018-12-31';
$sql = "SELECT sort_date, form FROM wp_booking WHERE date(sort_date) = $dato";
```

Best regards kresten

Comment: Your question not clear

Comment: to put simple just change sql statement to $sql = "SELECT sort_date, form FROM wp_booking WHERE date(sort_date) = '$dato'  "; as you need quotes around $dato to insure database can read where statement